# Python- How to handle error for RTSP link

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, rtsp

I've created a python script that checks muliple different urls and ports and detects if there is an RTSP stream on them - it is working fine, but it creates errors when the stream doesn't exist (which I'd obviously expect).

I'm getting `[rtsp @ 0x16745c0] method DESCRIBE failed: 451 ERROR`

What I want to do it add a line to my script so if I get the above error, then I just display it in a message on screen. I've tried the following with no luck:

```
for x in feedList:

    print("[INFO] Checking Link..." + x)

    cap=cv2.VideoCapture(x)

    try:

        # Check if camera opened successfully
        if (cap.isOpened()== True): 
            streamlink = x
            print("[INFO] FOUND! Stream Link..." + x)
            break
    except socket.error:
        print("[NO STREAM]" + x)
    except:
        print("[FAILED]" + x)
        pass
```

The Except cases never get hit, I always just get `[rtsp @ 0x16745c0] method DESCRIBE failed: 451 ERROR`

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the stream on the link does not exist, creating `VideoCapture` object on that link would still be successful but you will not be able to process on the object.

You code's control flow just might be going in and checking `if (cap.isOpened()== True)` but there is no `else` block to handle what would happen if `if (cap.isOpened() != True)`. So just try adding an `else` block to display the error message.

```
for x in feedList:

    print("[INFO] Checking Link..." + x)

    cap=cv2.VideoCapture(x)

    try:   
        # Check if camera opened successfully
        if (cap.isOpened()== True): 
            streamlink = x
            print("[INFO] FOUND! Stream Link..." + x)
            break
        # Else is important to display error message on the screen if can.isOpened returns false
        else
            print("[NO STREAM]" + x)
    except socket.error:
        print("[NO STREAM]" + x)
    except:
        print("[FAILED]" + x)
        pass
```

---

If this doesn't work: following might solve the issue:

> One of the main issues is that every camera manufacturer uses their
>   own protocol (RTSP URI formatting). Finding the correct URL for your
>   IP-camera can be frustrating and time-intensive. When found you can
>   try to open it with VLC, and afterwards with Kerberos.io.
>
> Depending on the format of the RTSP URI things can go wrong, for
>   example when using a format like above. To solve the problem you'll
>   need to add an question mark "?" at the end of the url.

As example original link might be:

```
rtsp://192.168.2.109:554/user=admin&password=mammaloe&channel=1&stream=0.sdp
```

So with `?` it would be:

```
rtsp://192.168.2.109:554/user=admin&password=mammaloe&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?
```

[Source](https://kerberosio.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/208377905-RTSP-stream-of-IP-camera-is-not-working)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I still get the same: [INFO] Checking Link...rtsp://xx.xxx.xx.x:554/mpeg/media.amp
[rtsp @ 0x18ad840] method DESCRIBE failed: 451 ERROR

Comment: Try adding a '?' at the RTSP link end, link: https://kerberosio.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/208377905-RTSP-stream-of-IP-camera-is-not-working

Comment: Thanks, Unfortunately that didn't work either (Alot of my links so have a ? at the end), it's a strange one. It's not essential as the code is working fine, I just like to handle error correctly

Comment: Try adding `else` to `if` of `cap.isOpened()` as updated in my answer

Comment: [INFO] Testing Link...rtsp://92.236.66.2/live1.sdp?
[rtsp @ 0x1bcc9c0] method DESCRIBE failed: 451 ERROR
[NO STREAM]rtsp://92.236.66.2/live1.sdp?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210653/discussion-between-futurejj-and-walshie1987).